# How to use Exoplayer in Adapter/RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, exoplayer2.x

This is my code that I wrote but when I click button to initialize ExpoPlayer it doesn't work.

```
  private  fun initializeExoplayer(){
      simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
          DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
          DefaultTrackSelector(adaptiveTrackSelectionFactory)
      )
      simpleExoPlayer.prepare(buildMediaSource())
      itemView.simpleExoPlayerView.player = simpleExoPlayer
      simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(playbackPosition)
      simpleExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
      simpleExoPlayer.addListener(this)
    }

    private fun buildMediaSource(): MediaSource {
      var uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://player.vimeo.com/external/357507131.m3u8?s=17a1326569611e13080cbe99344549fcc6b5613d")
      val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(context,"App Name"))
      return  HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(uri)

    }
```

I've tried with above code but it does't work anyone can help me for this issue???

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain exactly how it does not work. Is it crashing? Does it not do anything? Are you sure the `RecyclerView` click works? How have you determined that it does or does not? Have you put break points or log prints there? Which specific method does it fail in? How far does it get?

Comment: The url you are passing is not the final video url. Given url redirects to another url. Use the final url to play it.